# how get common elements of 2 different arrays and return an object containing the common elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have 2 arrays of objects

```
var array1 = [
{id: 1, name:'fruit', rating:5},
{id: 4, name:'vegetable', rating: 3},
{id: 8, name:'meat', rating:1}
];

var array2 = [
{alimentId: 1, quantity: 2},
{alimentId: 4, quantity: 2},
{alimentId: 8, quantity: 4}
]
```

and I want to get a new the array1 such that

```
var array = [
    {id: 1, name:'fruit'},
    {id: 4, name:'vegetable'},
]
```

which has only the elements with quantity 2 matching the alimentId with the id.
I'm always getting confused with arrays and objects manipulations.. Please help

Comment: `array2.filter(it => it.quantity === 2).map(it => array1.find(other => other.id === it.alignmentId))`

Comment: I updated the question... a new array without the rating is the output

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following code will solve your problem:

```
const func = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return arr1.filter(obj => {
    const objToCheck = arr2.filter(element => element.alimentId === obj.id);
    return objToCheck[0].quantity === 2;
  });  
};
```

You also can send the wanted value(2) and the key name(quantity) as params.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 = [
{id: 1, name:'fruit', rating:5},
{id: 4, name:'vegetable', rating: 3},
{id: 8, name:'meat', rating:1}
];

var array2 = [
{alimentId: 1, quantity: 2},
{alimentId: 4, quantity: 2},
{alimentId: 8, quantity: 4}
] 
       function filter(array1, array2) {
        return array1
         .filter(it => array2 // filter array1 by array2
           .filter(it => it.quantity === 2) // filter your array2 by field quantity = 2
           .map(it => it.alimentId) // pull out array of alimentId
           .includes(it.id) // check array2.alimentId includes array1.id
          )
        }

console.log(filter(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations when you answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```js
const common_elements = (arr1, arr2, quantity) => {
  let res = []
  arr1.forEach(el1 => {
    arr2.forEach(el2 => {
      if(el1.id === el2.alimentId && el2.quantity === quantity) {
        res.push(el1)
      }
    });
  });

  return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reduce:

```
var array3 = array1.reduce((acc ,val ,index) => {
if (val.id=array2[index].alimentId) {
acc =[...acc, {id: val.id, name: val.name}]
 }
return acc;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [
  {id: 1, name:'fruit', rating:5},
  {id: 4, name:'vegetable', rating: 3},
  {id: 8, name:'meat', rating:1}
];

var array2 = [
  {alimentId: 1, quantity: 2},
  {alimentId: 4, quantity: 2},
  {alimentId: 8, quantity: 4}
]

const commonArray = array2.filter(item => item.quantity === 2 && array1.find(el => el.id===item.alimentId));

console.log(commonArray)
```

Comment: `[
  {
    "alimentId": 1,
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "alimentId": 4,
    "quantity": 2
  }
]`
this is the output of your code, which is different from the expected output as mentioned... thanks for your reply though